# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, sockets, pipe, resin

I am getting this for all the database connections from my app server..
This exception occured for couple of hours, then got fixed by itself.
Something to do with network connection from the appserver?

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
com.inet.tds.SQLException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at com.inet.tds.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.a.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.tds.a.commit(Unknown Source)
    at com.inet.pool.a.commit(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL, "By default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if nothing has happened." And, MySQL has a reconnect feature that supports auto-reconnect after the closed connection is detected on the client side.

Eight hours? With the use of connection pooling or a long-running background job, that is possible.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 1):

It means you client has disconnected from the server; check if it is running. [See here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html)

Answer (score 1):

During a write the connection was severed, this can be due the the destination closing the connection or the destination process has terminated. Its not an error with your implementation.