# Problems with javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null

Tags: java, exception, webserver

Good afternoon people.

We have a very strange problem here. We have a webservice where many clients connect, and everything was OK until Tuesday when he began to appear the following exception on the console:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
 at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:112)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:284)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:339)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:93)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:481)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null
 at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:313)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:97)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:319)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
 ... 27 more
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:319)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:288)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:98)
 at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:99)
 at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
 at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
 ... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:741)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:299)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:981)
 at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:314)
```

The exception Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe at first think it is a problem with the DB, according to several articles report, but after various tests we did rule out that problem is related to the DB.

The only change in our system was that a customer has to send a larger number of transaction for us, otherwise no change.

Can anyone give us some light on this problem?

Thank you

Comment: SocketException has to deal with sending information over the internet. Can you please give more detail on the exact things that changed? Also, without any code we have no idea why anything's causing null exceptions, if you could just look at the error log and send us a little bit of the code on that file and near that line number it may be possible to help a lot more.

Comment: Found two posts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309561/how-to-fix-java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682560/java-net-socketexception-broken-pipe

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166843/broken-pipe-java-ee
It is being caused by abort of a request by client.