# Broken Pipe Error thrown with status code 200 OK from Spring Actuator /health endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a broken pipe error from my spring actuator `/health` endpoint for obvious reasons and I am not able to figure If the user need to handle this exception.

My error goes like this

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:62)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:97)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:124)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:826)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:773)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.end(Http11OutputBuffer.java:568)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.end(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:199)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.end(Http11OutputBuffer.java:235)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.finishResponse(Http11Processor.java:1222)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

The problem is that I am receiving this error with http status code `200 OK`.

How and where should I handle this error If I do not have any custom handling under `HealthIndicator` ?

Is it possible to catch this error and rethrow with a different error code. ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36570839/592355 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14166843/592355 ...

Comment: So 1. Who is "in charge" of the client. (Maybe it requests too often (this can be tuned)) 2. Do You need to worry about? 2a. how to catch/react: [looks reasonable & working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74304117/592355) (to be tested, 0 votes;(